# Converting rows to column values. Unique id with multiple code values

Tags: sql, pivot

I have this table:

| Enc_ID | CPT_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 234 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 |
| 3 | 123 |

and I want this:

| Enc_ID | CPT_CODE 1 | CPT_CODE 2 | CPT_CODE 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 234 |  |
| 2 | 123 | 456 |  |
| 3 | 123 |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Enc_ID ORDER BY CPT_CODE) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    Enc_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CPT_CODE END) AS CPT_CODE_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CPT_CODE END) AS CPT_CODE_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CPT_CODE END) AS CPT_CODE_3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Enc_ID;
```